# Not able to add email field in react web app

Tags: reactjs, forms, mobx

I am developing a small React App that is integrating with Mobx.  I have setup a members store which is the following:

```
import {observable, action, computed} from 'mobx';

 class MemberStore {
@observable members = [];

@action addMember(data) {
    const existing = this.members;
    this.members = existing.concat(data);
}

@computed get memberCount() {
    return this.members.length;
 }

}
const store = new MemberStore();
export default store;
```

Now I have a contact page which has a form of Name and email.  Now I am able to add a name but not the email.  So basically when I click the submit button I only get the name and a 0 next to the name.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import Jumbotron from '../components/Jumbotron';
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';

@inject('MemberStore')
@observer

class Contact extends Component {
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const member = this.member.value;
    const email = this.email.value;
    // const email = this.email.value;
    this.props.MemberStore.addMember(member, email);
    this.member.value = '';
    this.email.value = '';
}
render() {
    const {MemberStore} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Jumbotron title="Contact Page" subtitle="You want to get in touch"/>
            <div className="container">
               <h2>You have {MemberStore.memberCount} members.</h2>

               <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" ref={input => this.member = input }/>
                   <div>
                   <input type="text" placeholder= "Enter Your Email" ref={input => this.email = input }/>
                   </div>
                   <button>Submit</button>
               </form>
            <ul>
                {MemberStore.members.map((member,email) => (
                    <li key={member}>
                        {member}
                        {email}

                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
  }
 }

 export default Contact;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `addMember` takes one parameter `data`, and you’re passing two parameters to it when you call it: `addMember(name, email)`.

You should pass the name and email in as an object instead:

`addMember({name, email})`

Your code that maps the `MemberStore.members` array to JSX is also taking two parameters, when it should only take one object as a param:

`{MemberStore.members.map({member,email}) => (`

Note that I’m using the [ES6 Object Literal Property Value Shorthand](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand) syntax above.

Comment: Cheers Nathan. Will try this out tomorrow.

Comment: In the future, you should probably test the answer first before making it the ‘accepted’ answer.